# com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope is missing from the entitlement key?

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, mac-app-store, entitlements

In my cocoa app I have the entitlement `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope` added to my .entitlement

When I submit this app to the mac app store, I was asked to add entitlement. I click on the "entitlement" drop down, I just couldn't find this entitlement:

[image: available entitlemnets]

am I missing something here? or this entitlement doesn't need to be added when submitting app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the use of this entitlement when submitting to the App Store. You *may* no longer even need to include it in your app at all for bookmarks to work, but I don't *know* that always works and including it is harmless.